# Ambiguous System.Drawing.Image Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am trying to maintain the quality of images on re-size but system not allowed me to include the Image Class as it alert me to (Ambiguous Name Choose from choose from the following... System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image
System.Drawing.Image

As I  have already provided the namespace of System.Drawing & System.Web.UI.WebControls.

Actually I am trying it as follow:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
 System.Drawing.Image path = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("Dharm/shiv.jpg");//imageclass not allowed me to create the reference of the images
 Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(230,130);
 using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)) 
 {
   gr.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
   gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
   gr.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
   gr.DrawImage(path, new Rectangle(0, 0, 230, 130));

  }

  }
```

Don't know what's a wrong why system not allowed me to create object or reference of Images Class. What's wrong with it?.

Comment: @Bolu, Ok than can you tell me how to reference my image path from system.web.UI.WebControls.Image?.

Comment: Do a search, check are there any mismatches in your code. e.g.  `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image xx = new System.Drawing.Image()` or vise versa etc..

Comment: @Bolu, Don't know but System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image xx=new System.Drawing.Image cannot inherit the fromFile() Method.

Comment: I was suggesting you to do a search within your code for mismatches like that.... (e.g. check if in you code you are creating a `System.Drawing.Image` object with a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image` constructor or vise versa )

Comment: Ambiguous means that a class with name Image exists in the System.Drawing AND in the System.Web.UI namespace and the compiler cannot tell by guessing which one to use. So the simplest fix would be to remove either using System.Drawing; or using System.Web.UI; IF you don't really need both namespaces in the same class.